# Evaluating the definite integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^3 \theta}{2\theta - \sin 2\theta} \mathrm{d}\theta$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I'm interested in finding how and to what the following quantity evaluates out of integral form.
$$
\mathcal{I} = \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{R^2}{L^2} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^3 \theta}{2\theta - \sin 2\theta} \,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
This problem arises from an attempt of applying thin airfoil theory to a particularly shaped cone to find an estimate of its associated drag coefficient in a flow field.

The cone itself is given by the following parameterization
\begin{align}
\theta &= \cos^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{2x}{L}\right) && (0 \leq x \leq L) \\
y &= \frac{R}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sqrt{\theta - \frac{1}{2} \sin 2\theta + C \sin^3 \theta} && (0 \leq \theta \leq \pi).
\end{align}
Here, we really care only about $x$ as $\theta$ is just a convenience, $L$ is a positive constant as is $R$, and $C = 0$ finalizes the cone characterization. We are interested in integrating $((y \circ \theta)')^2$ on the interval for which $x$ is defined.

As such, we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= \frac{1}{L} \int_0^L \frac{32}{\pi} \frac{R^2}{L^4} \frac{(L - x) x}{2\theta(x) - \sin 2\theta(x)} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi \frac{32}{\pi} \frac{R^2}{L^4} \frac{(L - (L/2)(1 - \cos\theta)) \ (L/2)(1 - \cos\theta)}{2\theta - \sin 2\theta} \sin\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta && (\text{$x \to \theta$}) \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{R^2}{L^2} \int_0^\pi \frac{(1 + \cos\theta)(1 - \cos\theta)}{2\theta - \sin 2\theta} \sin\theta \,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{R^2}{L^2} \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^3\theta}{2\theta - \sin 2\theta} \,\mathrm{d}\theta.
\end{align}

This is where I'm stuck. I realize it can be simplified some more, like
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{R^2}{L^2} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^3 (\varphi / 2)}{\varphi - \sin \varphi} \,\mathrm{d}\varphi && (\theta = \varphi/2) \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi} \frac{R^2}{L^2} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sqrt{1 - \cos \varphi}^3}{\varphi - \sin \varphi} \,\mathrm{d}\varphi,
\end{align}
but I'm suspicious if these forms are more helpful than before. I thought maybe residue theorem might help, but I question the sole term $\varphi$ for this method.

In trying to numerically evaluate the integral in question (as written in the title), Matlab (trapz) and Mathematica (NIntegrate) both insist on differing values.
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{L^2}{R^2} \mathcal{I} &\sim 1.37368 && \text{(Matlab)} \\
\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{L^2}{R^2} \mathcal{I} &\sim 1.07903 && \text{(Mathematica)}.
\end{align}
Actually Matlab insists on NaN, but removing the first entry (so that the integrand is not indeterminate) gives that above.

How would one go about to evaluate this integral $\mathcal{I}$ and what is its precise value? Brownie points to go back to the beginning and do it for $C > 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "removing the first entry"? How do you get a numerical value for an expression that involves the free parameters $R$ and $L$? For the integral in the title, without those factors, Wolfram|Alpha gives $1.07903$. The fact that it doesn't give a closed form doesn't bode well...

Comment: @joriki Matlab uses vectorized (i.e. discrete) values for $\theta$ and the integrand, and the first value of the integrand happens to be indeterminant, which Matlab interprets as NaN (so the result is automatically NaN). Also good point. I was using particular values for $R$ and $L$. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1):

If there are problems because of the lower bound, what you could do is to compute
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin ^3(t)}{2 t-\sin (2 t)}\,dt=\int_0^\epsilon\frac{\sin ^3(t)}{2 t-\sin (2 t)}\,dt+\int_\epsilon^\pi\frac{\sin ^3(t)}{2 t-\sin (2 t)}\,dt$$
For the first integral, build a simple $[4,2]$ Padé approximant of the integrand around $t=0$ which makes
$$\frac{\sin ^3(t)}{2 t-\sin (2 t)}=-\frac{199665}{9464}+\frac{681 }{1456}t^2+\frac{42386415}{4732 \left(13 t^2+410\right)}$$ which is equivalent to a Taylor series to $O(t^8)$. So,
$$\int_0^\epsilon\frac{\sin ^3(t)}{2 t-\sin (2 t)}\,dt=-\frac{199665 }{9464}\epsilon+\frac{227 }{1456}\epsilon^3+\frac{206763 }{4732}\sqrt{\frac{205}{26}} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{13}{410}}\, \epsilon\right)$$
Let $\epsilon=10^{-k}$ and get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & I_1 & I_2 & I_1+I_2 \\
 0 & 0.679295758900725 & 0.3997399656052 & 1.0790357245059 \\
 1 & 0.074925043918625 & 1.0041090639795 & 1.0790341078981 \\
 2 & 0.007499925000439 & 1.0715341828992 & 1.0790341078996 \\
 3 & 0.000749999925000 & 1.0782841079748 & 1.0790341078998 \\
 4 & 0.000074999999925 & 1.0789591078999 & 1.0790341078998 \\
 5 & 0.000007499999993 & 1.0790266078998 & 1.0790341078998 \\
 6 & 0.000000749999999 & 1.0790333578998 & 1.0790341078998
\end{array}
\right)$$